# MPU-9150 XYZ values not outputting correctly

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

Below is a snippet of code from SparkFun and Adafruit that uses a MPU-9150 to output acceleration, gyroscope, and compass in 3 axes, to a display. I have attempted to modify the code so it prints to serial as I do not have a display to use. However, I always get the same output no matter the chips position or movement.

Output:

```
ax = 0.00 ay = 0.00 az = 0.00 mg
gx = 0.00 gy = 0.00 gz = 0.00 deg/s
mx = 0 my = 0 mz = 0 mG
q0 = 1.00 qx = 0.00 qy = 0.00 qz = 0.00
Yaw, Pitch, Roll: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
rate = 778.82 Hz
 x   y   z  0
0
0
mg
0
0
0
o/s
0
0
0
mG
0
0
0
ypr
```

Code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050_9Axis_MotionApps41.h"
//#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
//#include <Adafruit_PCD8544.h>

// Using NOKIA 5110 monochrome 84 x 48 pixel display
// pin 9 - Serial clock out (SCLK)
// pin 8 - Serial data out (DIN)
// pin 7 - Data/Command select (D/C)
// pin 5 - LCD chip select (CS)
// pin 6 - LCD reset (RST)
//Adafruit_PCD8544 display = Adafruit_PCD8544(9, 8, 7, 5, 6);

// Declare device MPU6050 class
MPU6050 mpu;

// global constants for 9 DoF fusion and AHRS (Attitude and Heading Reference System)
#define GyroMeasError PI * (40.0f / 180.0f)       // gyroscope measurement error in rads/s (shown as 3 deg/s)
#define GyroMeasDrift PI * (0.0f / 180.0f)      // gyroscope measurement drift in rad/s/s (shown as 0.0 deg/s/s)
// There is a tradeoff in the beta parameter between accuracy and response speed.
// In the original Madgwick study, beta of 0.041 (corresponding to GyroMeasError of 2.7 degrees/s) was found to give optimal accuracy.
// However, with this value, the LSM9SD0 response time is about 10 seconds to a stable initial quaternion.
// Subsequent changes also require a longish lag time to a stable output, not fast enough for a quadcopter or robot car!
// By increasing beta (GyroMeasError) by about a factor of fifteen, the response time constant is reduced to ~2 sec
// I haven't noticed any reduction in solution accuracy. This is essentially the I coefficient in a PID control sense; 
// the bigger the feedback coefficient, the faster the solution converges, usually at the expense of accuracy. 
// In any case, this is the free parameter in the Madgwick filtering and fusion scheme.
#define beta sqrt(3.0f / 4.0f) * GyroMeasError   // compute beta
#define zeta sqrt(3.0f / 4.0f) * GyroMeasDrift   // compute zeta, the other free parameter in the Madgwick scheme usually set to a small or zero value
#define Kp 2.0f * 5.0f // these are the free parameters in the Mahony filter and fusion scheme, Kp for proportional feedback, Ki for integral
#define Ki 0.0f

int16_t a1, a2, a3, g1, g2, g3, m1, m2, m3;     // raw data arrays reading
uint16_t count = 0;  // used to control display output rate
uint16_t delt_t = 0; // used to control display output rate
uint16_t mcount = 0; // used to control display output rate
uint8_t MagRate;     // read rate for magnetometer data

float pitch, yaw, roll;
float deltat = 0.0f;        // integration interval for both filter schemes
uint16_t lastUpdate = 0; // used to calculate integration interval
uint16_t now = 0;        // used to calculate integration interval

float ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz, mx, my, mz; // variables to hold latest sensor data values 
float q[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};    // vector to hold quaternion
float eInt[3] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};       // vector to hold integral error for Mahony method


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(38400); // Start serial at 38400 bps

  //display.begin(); // Initialize the display
  //display.setContrast(58); // Set the contrast
  //display.setRotation(0); //  0 or 2) width = width, 1 or 3) width = height, swapped etc.

// Start device display with ID of sensor
  /*
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setCursor(0,0);  display.print("MPU9150");
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(0, 20); display.print("9 DOF sensor");
  display.setCursor(0, 30); display.print("data fusion");
  display.setCursor(20, 40); display.print("AHRS");
  display.display();
  delay(2000);

// Set up for data display
  display.setTextSize(1); // Set text size to normal, 2 is twice normal etc.
  display.setTextColor(BLACK); // Set pixel color; 1 on the monochrome screen
  display.clearDisplay();   // clears the screen and buffer
  display.display();
    */       

    // initialize MPU6050 device
    Serial.println(F("Initializing I2C devices..."));
    mpu.initialize();

    // verify connection
    Serial.println(F("Testing device connections..."));
    Serial.println(mpu.testConnection() ? F("MPU9150 connection successful") : F("MPU9150 connection failed"));

// Set up the accelerometer, gyro, and magnetometer for data output

   mpu.setRate(7); // set gyro rate to 8 kHz/(1 * rate) shows 1 kHz, accelerometer ODR is fixed at 1 KHz

   MagRate = 10; // set magnetometer read rate in Hz; 10 to 100 (max) Hz are reasonable values

// Digital low pass filter configuration. 
// It also determines the internal sampling rate used by the device as shown in the table below.
// The accelerometer output rate is fixed at 1kHz. This means that for a Sample
// Rate greater than 1kHz, the same accelerometer sample may be output to the
// FIFO, DMP, and sensor registers more than once.
/*
 *          |   ACCELEROMETER    |           GYROSCOPE
 * DLPF_CFG | Bandwidth | Delay  | Bandwidth | Delay  | Sample Rate
 * ---------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+-------------
 * 0        | 260Hz     | 0ms    | 256Hz     | 0.98ms | 8kHz
 * 1        | 184Hz     | 2.0ms  | 188Hz     | 1.9ms  | 1kHz
 * 2        | 94Hz      | 3.0ms  | 98Hz      | 2.8ms  | 1kHz
 * 3        | 44Hz      | 4.9ms  | 42Hz      | 4.8ms  | 1kHz
 * 4        | 21Hz      | 8.5ms  | 20Hz      | 8.3ms  | 1kHz
 * 5        | 10Hz      | 13.8ms | 10Hz      | 13.4ms | 1kHz
 * 6        | 5Hz       | 19.0ms | 5Hz       | 18.6ms | 1kHz
 */
  mpu.setDLPFMode(4); // set bandwidth of both gyro and accelerometer to ~20 Hz

// Full-scale range of the gyro sensors:
// 0 = +/- 250 degrees/sec, 1 = +/- 500 degrees/sec, 2 = +/- 1000 degrees/sec, 3 = +/- 2000 degrees/sec
  mpu.setFullScaleGyroRange(0); // set gyro range to 250 degrees/sec

// Full-scale accelerometer range.
// The full-scale range of the accelerometer: 0 = +/- 2g, 1 = +/- 4g, 2 = +/- 8g, 3 = +/- 16g
  mpu.setFullScaleAccelRange(0); // set accelerometer to 2 g range

  mpu.setIntDataReadyEnabled(true); // enable data ready interrupt
}

void loop()
{
         if(mpu.getIntDataReadyStatus() == 1) { // wait for data ready status register to update all data registers
            mcount++;
           // read the raw sensor data
            mpu.getAcceleration  ( &a1, &a2, &a3  );
            ax = a1*2.0f/32768.0f; // 2 g full range for accelerometer
            ay = a2*2.0f/32768.0f;
            az = a3*2.0f/32768.0f;

            mpu.getRotation  ( &g1, &g2, &g3  );
            gx = g1*250.0f/32768.0f; // 250 deg/s full range for gyroscope
            gy = g2*250.0f/32768.0f;
            gz = g3*250.0f/32768.0f;
//  The gyros and accelerometers can in principle be calibrated in addition to any factory calibration but they are generally
//  pretty accurate. You can check the accelerometer by making sure the reading is +1 g in the positive direction for each axis.
//  The gyro should read zero for each axis when the sensor is at rest. Small or zero adjustment should be needed for these sensors.
//  The magnetometer is a different thing. Most magnetometers will be sensitive to circuit currents, computers, and 
//  other both man-made and natural sources of magnetic field. The rough way to calibrate the magnetometer is to record
//  the maximum and minimum readings (generally achieved at the North magnetic direction). The average of the sum divided by two
//  should provide a pretty good calibration offset. Don't forget that for the MPU9150, the magnetometer x- and y-axes are switched 
//  compared to the gyro and accelerometer!
            if (mcount > 1000/MagRate) {  // this is a poor man's way of setting the magnetometer read rate (see below) 
            mpu.getMag  ( &m1, &m2, &m3 );
            mx = m1*10.0f*1229.0f/4096.0f + 18.0f; // milliGauss (1229 microTesla per 2^12 bits, 10 mG per microTesla)
            my = m2*10.0f*1229.0f/4096.0f + 70.0f; // apply calibration offsets in mG that correspond to your environment and magnetometer
            mz = m3*10.0f*1229.0f/4096.0f + 270.0f;
            mcount = 0;
            }           
         }

  now = micros();
  deltat = ((now - lastUpdate)/1000000.0f); // set integration time by time elapsed since last filter update
  lastUpdate = now;
  // Sensors x (y)-axis of the accelerometer is aligned with the y (x)-axis of the magnetometer;
  // the magnetometer z-axis (+ down) is opposite to z-axis (+ up) of accelerometer and gyro!
  // We have to make some allowance for this orientationmismatch in feeding the output to the quaternion filter.
  // For the MPU-9150, we have chosen a magnetic rotation that keeps the sensor forward along the x-axis just like
  // in the LSM9DS0 sensor. This rotation can be modified to allow any convenient orientation convention.
  // This is ok by aircraft orientation standards!  
  // Pass gyro rate as rad/s
   MadgwickQuaternionUpdate(ax, ay, az, gx*PI/180.0f, gy*PI/180.0f, gz*PI/180.0f,  my,  mx, mz);
// MahonyQuaternionUpdate(ax, ay, az, gx*PI/180.0f, gy*PI/180.0f, gz*PI/180.0f, my, mx, mz);

    // Serial print and/or display at 0.5 s rate independent of data rates
    delt_t = millis() - count;
    if (delt_t > 500) { // update LCD once per half-second independent of read rate

    Serial.print("ax = "); Serial.print((int)1000*ax);  
    Serial.print(" ay = "); Serial.print((int)1000*ay); 
    Serial.print(" az = "); Serial.print((int)1000*az); Serial.println(" mg");
    Serial.print("gx = "); Serial.print( gx, 2); 
    Serial.print(" gy = "); Serial.print( gy, 2); 
    Serial.print(" gz = "); Serial.print( gz, 2); Serial.println(" deg/s");
    Serial.print("mx = "); Serial.print( (int)mx ); 
    Serial.print(" my = "); Serial.print( (int)my ); 
    Serial.print(" mz = "); Serial.print( (int)mz ); Serial.println(" mG");

    Serial.print("q0 = "); Serial.print(q[0]);
    Serial.print(" qx = "); Serial.print(q[1]); 
    Serial.print(" qy = "); Serial.print(q[2]); 
    Serial.print(" qz = "); Serial.println(q[3]); 


  // Define output variables from updated quaternion---these are Tait-Bryan angles, commonly used in aircraft orientation.
  // In this coordinate system, the positive z-axis is down toward Earth. 
  // Yaw is the angle between Sensor x-axis and Earth magnetic North (or true North if corrected for local declination, looking down on the sensor positive yaw is counterclockwise.
  // Pitch is angle between sensor x-axis and Earth ground plane, toward the Earth is positive, up toward the sky is negative.
  // Roll is angle between sensor y-axis and Earth ground plane, y-axis up is positive roll.
  // These arise from the definition of the homogeneous rotation matrix constructed from quaternions.
  // Tait-Bryan angles as well as Euler angles are non-commutative; that is, the get the correct orientation the rotations must be
  // applied in the correct order which for this configuration is yaw, pitch, and then roll.
  // For more see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles which has additional links.
    yaw   = atan2(2.0f * (q[1] * q[2] + q[0] * q[3]), q[0] * q[0] + q[1] * q[1] - q[2] * q[2] - q[3] * q[3]);   
    pitch = -asin(2.0f * (q[1] * q[3] - q[0] * q[2]));
    roll  = atan2(2.0f * (q[0] * q[1] + q[2] * q[3]), q[0] * q[0] - q[1] * q[1] - q[2] * q[2] + q[3] * q[3]);
    pitch *= 180.0f / PI;
    yaw   *= 180.0f / PI - 13.8; // Declination at Danville, California is 13 degrees 48 minutes and 47 seconds on 2014-04-04
    roll  *= 180.0f / PI;

    Serial.print("Yaw, Pitch, Roll: ");
    Serial.print(yaw, 2);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(pitch, 2);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.println(roll, 2);

    Serial.print("rate = "); Serial.print((float)1.0f/deltat, 2); Serial.println(" Hz");

    /*
    display.clearDisplay();


    display.setCursor(0, 0); display.print(" x   y   z  ");

    display.setCursor(0,  8); display.print((int)(1000*ax)); 
    display.setCursor(24, 8); display.print((int)(1000*ay)); 
    display.setCursor(48, 8); display.print((int)(1000*az)); 
    display.setCursor(72, 8); display.print("mg");

    display.setCursor(0,  16); display.print((int)(gx)); 
    display.setCursor(24, 16); display.print((int)(gy)); 
    display.setCursor(48, 16); display.print((int)(gz)); 
    display.setCursor(66, 16); display.print("o/s");    

    display.setCursor(0,  24); display.print((int)(mx)); 
    display.setCursor(24, 24); display.print((int)(my)); 
    display.setCursor(48, 24); display.print((int)(mz)); 
    display.setCursor(72, 24); display.print("mG");    

    display.setCursor(0,  32); display.print((int)(yaw)); 
    display.setCursor(24, 32); display.print((int)(pitch)); 
    display.setCursor(48, 32); display.print((int)(roll)); 
    display.setCursor(66, 32); display.print("ypr");  

    // With these settings the filter is updating at a ~145 Hz rate using the Madgwick scheme and 
    // >200 Hz using the Mahony scheme even though the display refreshes at only 2 Hz.
    // The filter update rate is determined mostly by the mathematical steps in the respective algorithms, 
    // the processor speed (8 MHz for the 3.3V Pro Mini), and the magnetometer ODR:
    // an ODR of 10 Hz for the magnetometer produce the above rates, maximum magnetometer ODR of 100 Hz produces
    // filter update rates of 36 - 145 and ~38 Hz for the Madgwick and Mahony schemes, respectively. 
    // This is presumably because the magnetometer read takes longer than the gyro or accelerometer reads.
    // This filter update rate should be fast enough to maintain accurate platform orientation for 
    // stabilization control of a fast-moving robot or quadcopter. Compare to the update rate of 200 Hz
    // produced by the on-board Digital Motion Processor of Invensense's MPU6050 6 DoF and MPU9150 9DoF sensors.
    // The 3.3 V 8 MHz Pro Mini is doing pretty well!
    display.setCursor(0, 40); display.print("rt: "); display.print((1/deltat)); display.print(" Hz"); 

    display.display();
    count = millis();
    */
    Serial.print(" x   y   z  ");

    Serial.println((int)(1000*ax)); 
    Serial.println((int)(1000*ay)); 
    Serial.println((int)(1000*az)); 
    Serial.println("mg");
    Serial.println((int)(gx)); 
    Serial.println((int)(gy)); 
    Serial.println((int)(gz)); 
    Serial.println("o/s");    

    Serial.println((int)(mx)); 
    Serial.println((int)(my)); 
    Serial.println((int)(mz)); 
    Serial.println("mG");    

    Serial.println((int)(yaw)); 
    Serial.println((int)(pitch)); 
    Serial.println((int)(roll)); 
    Serial.println("ypr");
    }
}


// Implementation of Sebastian Madgwick's "...efficient orientation filter for... inertial/magnetic sensor arrays"
// (see http://www.x-io.co.uk/category/open-source/ for examples and more details)
// which fuses acceleration, rotation rate, and magnetic moments to produce a quaternion-based estimate of absolute
// device orientation -- which can be converted to yaw, pitch, and roll. Useful for stabilizing quadcopters, etc.
// The performance of the orientation filter is at least as good as conventional Kalman-based filtering algorithms
// but is much less computationally intensive---it can be performed on a 3.3 V Pro Mini operating at 8 MHz!
        void MadgwickQuaternionUpdate(float ax, float ay, float az, float gx, float gy, float gz, float mx, float my, float mz)
        {
            float q1 = q[0], q2 = q[1], q3 = q[2], q4 = q[3];   // short name local variable for readability
            float norm;
            float hx, hy, _2bx, _2bz;
            float s1, s2, s3, s4;
            float qDot1, qDot2, qDot3, qDot4;

            // Auxiliary variables to avoid repeated arithmetic
            float _2q1mx;
            float _2q1my;
            float _2q1mz;
            float _2q2mx;
            float _4bx;
            float _4bz;
            float _2q1 = 2.0f * q1;
            float _2q2 = 2.0f * q2;
            float _2q3 = 2.0f * q3;
            float _2q4 = 2.0f * q4;
            float _2q1q3 = 2.0f * q1 * q3;
            float _2q3q4 = 2.0f * q3 * q4;
            float q1q1 = q1 * q1;
            float q1q2 = q1 * q2;
            float q1q3 = q1 * q3;
            float q1q4 = q1 * q4;
            float q2q2 = q2 * q2;
            float q2q3 = q2 * q3;
            float q2q4 = q2 * q4;
            float q3q3 = q3 * q3;
            float q3q4 = q3 * q4;
            float q4q4 = q4 * q4;

            // Normalise accelerometer measurement
            norm = sqrt(ax * ax + ay * ay + az * az);
            if (norm == 0.0f) return; // handle NaN
            norm = 1.0f/norm;
            ax *= norm;
            ay *= norm;
            az *= norm;

            // Normalise magnetometer measurement
            norm = sqrt(mx * mx + my * my + mz * mz);
            if (norm == 0.0f) return; // handle NaN
            norm = 1.0f/norm;
            mx *= norm;
            my *= norm;
            mz *= norm;

            // Reference direction of Earth's magnetic field
            _2q1mx = 2.0f * q1 * mx;
            _2q1my = 2.0f * q1 * my;
            _2q1mz = 2.0f * q1 * mz;
            _2q2mx = 2.0f * q2 * mx;
            hx = mx * q1q1 - _2q1my * q4 + _2q1mz * q3 + mx * q2q2 + _2q2 * my * q3 + _2q2 * mz * q4 - mx * q3q3 - mx * q4q4;
            hy = _2q1mx * q4 + my * q1q1 - _2q1mz * q2 + _2q2mx * q3 - my * q2q2 + my * q3q3 + _2q3 * mz * q4 - my * q4q4;
            _2bx = sqrt(hx * hx + hy * hy);
            _2bz = -_2q1mx * q3 + _2q1my * q2 + mz * q1q1 + _2q2mx * q4 - mz * q2q2 + _2q3 * my * q4 - mz * q3q3 + mz * q4q4;
            _4bx = 2.0f * _2bx;
            _4bz = 2.0f * _2bz;

            // Gradient decent algorithm corrective step
            s1 = -_2q3 * (2.0f * q2q4 - _2q1q3 - ax) + _2q2 * (2.0f * q1q2 + _2q3q4 - ay) - _2bz * q3 * (_2bx * (0.5f - q3q3 - q4q4) + _2bz * (q2q4 - q1q3) - mx) + (-_2bx * q4 + _2bz * q2) * (_2bx * (q2q3 - q1q4) + _2bz * (q1q2 + q3q4) - my) + _2bx * q3 * (_2bx * (q1q3 + q2q4) + _2bz * (0.5f - q2q2 - q3q3) - mz);
            s2 = _2q4 * (2.0f * q2q4 - _2q1q3 - ax) + _2q1 * (2.0f * q1q2 + _2q3q4 - ay) - 4.0f * q2 * (1.0f - 2.0f * q2q2 - 2.0f * q3q3 - az) + _2bz * q4 * (_2bx * (0.5f - q3q3 - q4q4) + _2bz * (q2q4 - q1q3) - mx) + (_2bx * q3 + _2bz * q1) * (_2bx * (q2q3 - q1q4) + _2bz * (q1q2 + q3q4) - my) + (_2bx * q4 - _4bz * q2) * (_2bx * (q1q3 + q2q4) + _2bz * (0.5f - q2q2 - q3q3) - mz);
            s3 = -_2q1 * (2.0f * q2q4 - _2q1q3 - ax) + _2q4 * (2.0f * q1q2 + _2q3q4 - ay) - 4.0f * q3 * (1.0f - 2.0f * q2q2 - 2.0f * q3q3 - az) + (-_4bx * q3 - _2bz * q1) * (_2bx * (0.5f - q3q3 - q4q4) + _2bz * (q2q4 - q1q3) - mx) + (_2bx * q2 + _2bz * q4) * (_2bx * (q2q3 - q1q4) + _2bz * (q1q2 + q3q4) - my) + (_2bx * q1 - _4bz * q3) * (_2bx * (q1q3 + q2q4) + _2bz * (0.5f - q2q2 - q3q3) - mz);
            s4 = _2q2 * (2.0f * q2q4 - _2q1q3 - ax) + _2q3 * (2.0f * q1q2 + _2q3q4 - ay) + (-_4bx * q4 + _2bz * q2) * (_2bx * (0.5f - q3q3 - q4q4) + _2bz * (q2q4 - q1q3) - mx) + (-_2bx * q1 + _2bz * q3) * (_2bx * (q2q3 - q1q4) + _2bz * (q1q2 + q3q4) - my) + _2bx * q2 * (_2bx * (q1q3 + q2q4) + _2bz * (0.5f - q2q2 - q3q3) - mz);
            norm = sqrt(s1 * s1 + s2 * s2 + s3 * s3 + s4 * s4);    // normalise step magnitude
            norm = 1.0f/norm;
            s1 *= norm;
            s2 *= norm;
            s3 *= norm;
            s4 *= norm;

            // Compute rate of change of quaternion
            qDot1 = 0.5f * (-q2 * gx - q3 * gy - q4 * gz) - beta * s1;
            qDot2 = 0.5f * (q1 * gx + q3 * gz - q4 * gy) - beta * s2;
            qDot3 = 0.5f * (q1 * gy - q2 * gz + q4 * gx) - beta * s3;
            qDot4 = 0.5f * (q1 * gz + q2 * gy - q3 * gx) - beta * s4;

            // Integrate to yield quaternion
            q1 += qDot1 * deltat;
            q2 += qDot2 * deltat;
            q3 += qDot3 * deltat;
            q4 += qDot4 * deltat;
            norm = sqrt(q1 * q1 + q2 * q2 + q3 * q3 + q4 * q4);    // normalise quaternion
            norm = 1.0f/norm;
            q[0] = q1 * norm;
            q[1] = q2 * norm;
            q[2] = q3 * norm;
            q[3] = q4 * norm;

        }



 // Similar to Madgwick scheme but uses proportional and integral filtering on the error between estimated reference vectors and
 // measured ones. 
            void MahonyQuaternionUpdate(float ax, float ay, float az, float gx, float gy, float gz, float mx, float my, float mz)
        {
            float q1 = q[0], q2 = q[1], q3 = q[2], q4 = q[3];   // short name local variable for readability
            float norm;
            float hx, hy, bx, bz;
            float vx, vy, vz, wx, wy, wz;
            float ex, ey, ez;
            float pa, pb, pc;

            // Auxiliary variables to avoid repeated arithmetic
            float q1q1 = q1 * q1;
            float q1q2 = q1 * q2;
            float q1q3 = q1 * q3;
            float q1q4 = q1 * q4;
            float q2q2 = q2 * q2;
            float q2q3 = q2 * q3;
            float q2q4 = q2 * q4;
            float q3q3 = q3 * q3;
            float q3q4 = q3 * q4;
            float q4q4 = q4 * q4;   

            // Normalise accelerometer measurement
            norm = sqrt(ax * ax + ay * ay + az * az);
            if (norm == 0.0f) return; // handle NaN
            norm = 1.0f / norm;        // use reciprocal for division
            ax *= norm;
            ay *= norm;
            az *= norm;

            // Normalise magnetometer measurement
            norm = sqrt(mx * mx + my * my + mz * mz);
            if (norm == 0.0f) return; // handle NaN
            norm = 1.0f / norm;        // use reciprocal for division
            mx *= norm;
            my *= norm;
            mz *= norm;

            // Reference direction of Earth's magnetic field
            hx = 2.0f * mx * (0.5f - q3q3 - q4q4) + 2.0f * my * (q2q3 - q1q4) + 2.0f * mz * (q2q4 + q1q3);
            hy = 2.0f * mx * (q2q3 + q1q4) + 2.0f * my * (0.5f - q2q2 - q4q4) + 2.0f * mz * (q3q4 - q1q2);
            bx = sqrt((hx * hx) + (hy * hy));
            bz = 2.0f * mx * (q2q4 - q1q3) + 2.0f * my * (q3q4 + q1q2) + 2.0f * mz * (0.5f - q2q2 - q3q3);

            // Estimated direction of gravity and magnetic field
            vx = 2.0f * (q2q4 - q1q3);
            vy = 2.0f * (q1q2 + q3q4);
            vz = q1q1 - q2q2 - q3q3 + q4q4;
            wx = 2.0f * bx * (0.5f - q3q3 - q4q4) + 2.0f * bz * (q2q4 - q1q3);
            wy = 2.0f * bx * (q2q3 - q1q4) + 2.0f * bz * (q1q2 + q3q4);
            wz = 2.0f * bx * (q1q3 + q2q4) + 2.0f * bz * (0.5f - q2q2 - q3q3);  

            // Error is cross product between estimated direction and measured direction of gravity
            ex = (ay * vz - az * vy) + (my * wz - mz * wy);
            ey = (az * vx - ax * vz) + (mz * wx - mx * wz);
            ez = (ax * vy - ay * vx) + (mx * wy - my * wx);
            if (Ki > 0.0f)
            {
                eInt[0] += ex;      // accumulate integral error
                eInt[1] += ey;
                eInt[2] += ez;
            }
            else
            {
                eInt[0] = 0.0f;     // prevent integral wind up
                eInt[1] = 0.0f;
                eInt[2] = 0.0f;
            }

            // Apply feedback terms
            gx = gx + Kp * ex + Ki * eInt[0];
            gy = gy + Kp * ey + Ki * eInt[1];
            gz = gz + Kp * ez + Ki * eInt[2];

            // Integrate rate of change of quaternion
            pa = q2;
            pb = q3;
            pc = q4;
            q1 = q1 + (-q2 * gx - q3 * gy - q4 * gz) * (0.5f * deltat);
            q2 = pa + (q1 * gx + pb * gz - pc * gy) * (0.5f * deltat);
            q3 = pb + (q1 * gy - pa * gz + pc * gx) * (0.5f * deltat);
            q4 = pc + (q1 * gz + pa * gy - pb * gx) * (0.5f * deltat);

            // Normalise quaternion
            norm = sqrt(q1 * q1 + q2 * q2 + q3 * q3 + q4 * q4);
            norm = 1.0f / norm;
            q[0] = q1 * norm;
            q[1] = q2 * norm;
            q[2] = q3 * norm;
            q[3] = q4 * norm;

        }
```

Comment: Do you access the MPU by its FIFO ?

Comment: @LM.Croisez What exactly is FIFO? All I know is I am using I2C to connect and transfer data.

Comment: All modern accelerometers provide a FIFO (a buffer of type First-in-first-out, which allows the accelerometer to put samples into it, and warn the external processor by an interrupt when it is has to be read.
The read operation cause the accelerometer to fill it again, and so on.
This is a very usefull feature (a must), because while the FIFO is filled-in by the accelerometer, the processor can do a lot of other things, which can be, for example, doing calculation of former FIFO data, or whatever.

Comment: Why don't you access the Digital motion processor doing all the things for you?

Comment: there was the same issue with me but the actual reason was in loose connection of wires.

Answer (score 1):

There is some code here that you could have a look to: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-9150
Also, have a look here: https://github.com/zeran/MPU9150Lib
It seems interresting for you.